# Google Place Details Lat/Long coordinates not matching cross platform Maps URLs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have used the Google [Place details API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) to get the place details which includes the lat/lng coordinates of a place.

When I launch Google maps using the Universal cross-platform [Maps URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide), it does not recognize the Place.

For example,

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJbf8C1yFxdDkR3n12P4DkKt0&key=XXXXXXXX
```

returns the place details including the following location data:

```
 {
  .....
  "geometry": {
    "location": {
      "lat": 27.1750151,
      "lng": 78.0421552
    },
    "viewport": {
      "northeast": {
        "lat": 27.1770292,
        "lng": 78.04537599999999
      },
      "southwest": {
        "lat": 27.16897280000001,
        "lng": 78.0388188
      }
    }
  },
  .....
  "name": "Taj Mahal",
  "place_id": "ChIJbf8C1yFxdDkR3n12P4DkKt0",

  .....
}
```

But this data, when used to create a [Maps URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) with [direction map action](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action), does not give the correct place in the destination field.

Google Maps URL : https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=27.1750151,78.0421552&destination_place_id=ChIJbf8C1yFxdDkR3n12P4DkKt0

The destination is not shown as a place. Only the lat/lng or address is used as below.

[image: Google Map URL with directions action]

The correct/expected result is the following. Look at the destination.

[image: The Expected result of opening the Maps URL]

**Update**

The issue seems to be with the PlaceID not matching the lat/lng coordinates in the Maps URL. There seems to be an inconsistency with lat/lng provided by the Place Details API.

Below URL works

> https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=27.1750151,78.0421552,15z&destination_place_id=ChIJbf8C1yFxdDkR3n12P4DkKt0

but `27.1750151,78.0421552,15z` is not the coordinates from the [Place details API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details). The lat/lng returned by PlaceDetails API is `27.1750151,78.0421552`.

There is a difference of `,15z` which I believe it is the [zoom levels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#zoom-levels).

Comment: What is this place id? How did you first get it? What do you expect with the request you provided? It's good to provide examples, but please also let us know "what's wrong".

Comment: PlaceID have been taken using  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder . I have added screenshots. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `destination` parameter looks to be trumping the `destination_place_id` parameter completely when lat/lngs are supplied, causing a reverse geocode on the coordinates. In the following example URL, I'm using a Place ID of `ChIJj61dQgK6j4AR4GeTYWZsKWw` which corresponds to the Googleplex in Mountain View, CA as the `destination_place_id` along with the lat/lng for the Taj Mahal as the `destination`; notice the Googleplex query is ignored, and a reverse geocode is performed getting just the address in India:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=27.1750151,78.0421552&destination_place_id=ChIJj61dQgK6j4AR4GeTYWZsKWw

[image]

So, the workaround is to not use a lat/lng as the `destination` parameter. I've tested with various strings (place names, addresses, gibberish) as that parameter, and the `destination_place_id` appears to supercede it, which is the desired behavior. When using just a `.`(period) as a universal value, the name of the place along with the address is supplied:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=.&destination_place_id=ChIJj61dQgK6j4AR4GeTYWZsKWw

[image]

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=.&destination_place_id=ChIJbf8C1yFxdDkR3n12P4DkKt0

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The documentation mentions for `destination` that *The value can be either a place name, address, or comma-separated latitude/longitude coordinates.*

If you enter coordinates, I suppose it just does a reverse geocode and displays the corresponding address. So you can input the place name and it will work.

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Taj+Mahal&destination_place_id=ChIJbf8C1yFxdDkR3n12P4DkKt0

Comment: I know it works with a place name. Even if you don't give the PlaceID also it works https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=Taj+Mahal. But we need to give the exact name and there could be ambiguity.

Comment: So what? Why don't you pass the appropriate place name you got with the place ID as the `destination` param then?

Comment: I need it with the lat/lng. I'm storing only the lat/lng and placeID for later use with Google Maps URL...which is not taking the lat/lng. Please check the other answer.

Comment: Yes, then why don't you store the place name as well? Instead of using some undocumented hack.